# os.mkdir error- system cannot find the specified path

Tags: python-2.7, mkdir

I am trying to create new folders using dictionary keys. The code is:

```
os.mkdir("Y:\\Bleeding-study\\MIMIC\\Notes\\randombins\\")

for key in index:
    os.mkdir("Y:\\Bleeding-study\\MIMIC\\Notes\\randombins\\batch_%s\\"%str(key))
    os.mkdir("Y:\\Bleeding-study\\MIMIC\\Notes\\randombins\\batch_%s\\%s\\"%(str(key),"config"))
    os.mkdir("Y:\\Bleeding-study\\MIMIC\\Notes\\randombins\\batch_%s\\corpus\\"%str(key))
```

The error is:
`WindowsError: [Error 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'Y:\\Bleeding-study\\MIMIC\\Notes\\randombins\\batch_0\\'`

I thought this code would create that file pathname, so why is it giving this error?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Your error is because you are trying to create multiple levels of directory in one step.  `os.mkdir()` will only create a single level of directory, so this line fails:

`os.mkdir("Y:\\Bleeding-study\\MIMIC\\Notes\\randombins\\batch_%s\\"%str(key))`
because you have not yet created the `batch_0` directory.

[`os.makedirs()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs) is what you need here:

> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all
> intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
> ...

...and in fact if you use this, then you can do away with the initial `os.mkdir()`, as it will be redundant.